# Jquery-ui select menu with icon - select not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a jquery-ui select menu containing icons, however when clicked the select function is not called.

Items which have text respond to click correctly see below:

Thx!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu").menu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu li {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/24-128.png" height=20 width=20 />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/24/cloud-download-128.png" height=20 width=20>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

I found that for some reason jqueryUI is giving the images a divider class instead of a menu item class.

I can solve my issue by adding an extra div like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu").menu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu li {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>
    <div class="ui-menu-item">
      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/24-128.png" height=20 width=20 />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="ui-menu-item">
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/24/cloud-download-128.png" height=20 width=20>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I still hope a better solution/explanation is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [jQuery UI Menu Widget documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/), it treats all list items with space or dash as a menu divider (read [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-_isDivider)).

In your case, I think because you have nothing on the menu item except an image, the item is treated as a divider.

But the widget uses functional CSS classes which you can use to tell the widget that the image is in fact a menu item rather than a divider. You can give your menu item `img` tag a class named `ui-menu-item`. So you can have:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>
    <img class="ui-menu-item" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/24-128.png" height=20 width=20 />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="ui-menu-item" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/material-core/24/cloud-download-128.png" height=20 width=20>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or as you did, you wrapped your `img` within a `div` with the said class.

Another option is to override the widget's [`_isDivider`](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#method-_isDivider) function. But this is less efficient in your case.